# Average WSUS synchronisation data usage?

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, wsus

Recently, I configured our SBS2008 server to use WSUS. I set up a daily synchronisation, removed the packages that were of no interest / use to my domain and let it do it's thing.

Lo and behold, three days later I noticed that the synchronisation process had been pulling ~11GB/day. After disabling it, our usage went back down to normal levels.

Is this typical of WSUS, or have I seriously mis-configured something?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what update classifications you've chosen. If you have a lot of OS and products chosen, there can easily be 100+ GB of patches. Once the initial synchronization is done, you'll only ever download new updates, so I'd let it run it's course unless you have a reason not to.